# iPhone - UIImageView moves when Rotate Animation > 90 degree

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I'm using this code to Rotate my image.

```
- (IBAction)spin:(id)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.imgRad.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(arc4random() % 360 * M_PI / 180);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Now I have two problems.

**first:** If the random number is greater than 90, the image moves with its center closer to the right corner. And its in relation to the random number. So  higher number = the image's position is closer to the right corner. How can I fix that? Do I have to set a new center of my `UIImageView` every time its greater than 90?

**second:** If the number is for example 300, the image doesn't rotate 300 degrees, it just rotates 60 degrees the other way. How can i fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first problem may cause by the wrong anchor point when using transform which can avoid using `CAAnimation`.
- The second problem can be solved using `NSNumber`.

The code :

```
    CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(arc4random() % 360 * M_PI / 180)];
    rotation.duration = 5.0f;
    rotation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    rotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    [self.imgRad.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotatationRandom"];
```

Comment: maybe one more question: how can i set that the animation begin from the last state (like the method "setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState) because i want if i start the animation again, I want that the animation starts from the position where it stopped

Comment: Just keep the `toValue` of the previous rotation and use it as the `fromValue` for the current rotation.